# ElasticSearch update API - add fieldname starting with @ sign

Tags: elasticsearch

The ES update API can't set a new field if its name starts with an @:

```
{ 
  "script" : "ctx._source.@timestamp = 20120101000000"
}
```

anybody else stumbled upon this before? is there `ctx._source.remove()` equivalent for adding fieldnames which I could try as a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `["fieldname"]` notation:

```
{
    "script" : "ctx._source[\"@timestamp\"] = 20120101000000"
}'
```

or `put` method:

```
{ 
    "script" : "ctx._source.put(\"@timestamp\", 20120101000001)"
}
```

Comment: put.... hehe. Tried "add" before but didn't try more of the "standard verbs". thx!